# Google cloud add firewall rule to receive traffic from only certain IP's

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am trying to add a firewall rule to allow traffic from certain IP's, I selected **Source filter** as **IP ranges**, and in **Source IP ranges** I am adding (My IP/32), but the thing is the rule is not allowing my IP to receive the traffic.

Can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: We need more info, please share some screenshots of the firewall configuration and the networking configuration of the machine using this firewall. Check the networking tags and the ports.

Comment: @LuísBrito ports are opened because if I will allow 0.0.0.0/0 then I am receiving traffic, but changing it to (MY IP/32) isn't allowing my IP to receive the traffic.

Comment: Assuming everything in the firewall configuration is correct, maybe the problem is a clashing of different rules with different priorities. Check this -> https://serverfault.com/questions/901364/restrict-access-to-single-ip-only

Comment: @LuísBrito Yes I have already checked the post, but it is not working :(

Comment: I would try to investigate the public IP you are trying to use, if all configurations are right, maybe Google is getting another IP from this machine. Check for routers, proxies in between the connection. Maybe using some tool like -> https://www.ipify.org/

Comment: I have tried many websites, ipify too, and I have added that IP only in my firewall rule, but it ain't working.

Comment: I think it may be more reliable to check your IP directly on the target machine, beside using ipify etc.
You can try to temporary change firewall rule again to 0.0.0.0/0, connect to the target machine and check IPs of active connections on the VM itself with something like netstat.

Comment: Based on the "google-app-engine" tag, I understand that you are using GAE. Just to confirm, are you changing the [App Engine firewall rules](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/creating-firewalls#creating_firewall_rules) or the ones in VPC network? If you are using the first ones, I would try the check that [Oleksandr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4888849/oleksandr-bushkovskyi) suggested.

Comment: @RubénC. I am using VPC network.

Comment: Can you confirm that you are using App Engine, please? If so, try to follow the instructions in the [link that I mentioned](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/creating-firewalls#creating_firewall_rules).

Comment: @RubénC. I am creating rules for my compute engine instances.

Comment: Then I understand that this issue is not related to App Engine. Taking into account that this issue is related to network, you should move it to Stack Exchange, as suggested in this [topic guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

you only want to allow one IP, not a full range, that is something really different...

Try removing the /32 behind the IP address this will only allow your ip, no need of more to make it work.